# Suddenly msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail is unresponsive

Tags: sql-server

As of today, for just an hour ago, all calls to msdbo.dbo.sp_send_dbmail is unresponsive. I've successfully used it to send mail daily for at least a year, but now the query never stops executing. I've not changed the query.

In an attempt to troubleshoot I executed this query:

```
SELECT items.subject ,
   items.recipients ,
   items.copy_recipients ,
   items.blind_copy_recipients ,
   items.last_mod_date ,
   l.description
   FROM   msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems AS items
   LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log AS l 
                ON items.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id
   WHERE  items.last_mod_date > DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE())
```

This is also unresponsive.

How can I resolve this, and troubleshoot this?

Comment: when the above query is unresponsive,you will have to check wait stats or check for just some few records

Comment: as for `sp_send_dbmail` is unresponsive,i recommend checking for any changes done and also check the log  by right clicking sql agent

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you plese elaborate which log do you want me to look at?